# The dialog size in running is different from that in the designer on Qt

Tags: qt, dialog, window, size

The dialog size in running is different from that in the designer on Qt.

[image]

I have tried to solve by changing the setting to different choices in property but no help.

[image]

How to solve it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Isn't it the status bar at the bottom ?

Comment: I removed the status bar.

Comment: I don't quite see what the problem is. Your expectation that the appearance in the designer will be the same as in a running application is wrong. Setting a fixed size policy for a widget without setting a relevant size **constraint** on the widget's topmost layout is pointless. As far as I'm concerned, everything works as designed. If there's something that you don't like, don't refer to what designer is showing. Tell us *explicitly* what you expect, what you see, and how you want the widget to behave.

Comment: Are you actually asking: How to remove extra empty space at the bottom of a dialog window?

Answer (score 1):

You can resize your window after creating it:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
resize(581, 538);
```

Change those values until you get the size you want